# How to connect using UDP to my pic32 and get an answer from it

Tags: qt, sockets, udp, pic32

I want to connet with Qt on windows to my PIC32 UDP server. With a test program in C, I can connect and get the answer, but with Qt it is impossible. What am I doing wrong ?

As you can see **I use an ACTIVE WAITING** with the while, and **my slot doesn't seems to be triggered**. Maybe you can see my mistake here ? I hate active waiting....

Here is my code on Qt :

```cpp
void MuTweezer::run()
{    

    QHostAddress sender;
    quint16 senderPort;
    QByteArray datagram;
    qint64 pendingBytes;
    int cpt = 0;
    
    // Message to send
    QByteArray message("Hello that's charly");

    // m_imuRcvSocket.bind(10000); why is it for in a client side !?

    // SEEMS to NOT BE TRIGGERED
    connect(&m_imuRcvSocket, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(recu()));

    while(m_isRunning && cpt++ < 10)
    {
        // send the initial message
        qint64 bytesSent= m_imuRcvSocket.writeDatagram(message, QHostAddress("192.168.0.15"), 10000);

        cout << "Bytes sent : " << bytesSent << endl;

        // We wait the answer from the server
        while(!m_imuRcvSocket.hasPendingDatagrams());

        // If there is no datagram available, this function returns -1
        if((pendingBytes = m_imuRcvSocket.pendingDatagramSize()) == -1)
            continue;

        datagram.resize(pendingBytes);
        m_imuRcvSocket.readDatagram(datagram.data(), datagram.size(),
                                        &sender, &senderPort);

        cout << "================="
             << "\nMessage from <" << sender.toString().toStdString().substr(7) << "> on port " << senderPort
             << "\nString : " << datagram.data()
             << "\nSize: " << pendingBytes << " Bytes (characters)\n"
             << "=================" <<
        endl;

    }
}
```

Here is my code on the PIC32, as you can see, once I receive a message, I send the answer, it allows me to make a bidirectionnal communication :

```c
if(!UDPIsOpened(mySocket)){
    DBPRINTF("Socket CLOSED");
    continue; // go back to loop beginning
}

DBPRINTF("Socket OPEN");

if(!(lengthToGet = UDPIsGetReady(mySocket)))
    continue;

// get the string
// UDPGetArray : returns the number of bytes successfully read from the UDP buffer.
if((lengthWeGot = UDPGetArray(message, lengthToGet)))
    UDPDiscard(); // Discards any remaining RX data from a UDP socket.

/* Modifie it and send it back */
if(UDPIsPutReady(mySocket)){
    message[20]= 'Z';
    message[21]= 'i';
    message[22]= 'b';
    message[23]= 'o';

    UDPPutArray(message, lengthWeGot);
    UDPFlush();
}
```

Any idea ?

Comment: Do you have an event loop anywhere?  `Qt` is event based and without an event loop nothing much will happen.

Comment: Yes @G.M this code is embedded in a loop, inside a thread. The code runs, no problem with that.

Comment: Please show all of that code including the event loop.  Preferably in the form of a [mcve].  In the code shown the problem is that you never return control to the event loop between the call to `writeDatagram` and the call to `readDatagram`.

Comment: Hi @G.M. and thanks for your help, I'm a little bit desperate. I copied my entiere function. I repeat, it works perfectly fine with a small [serverUDP.c](https://pastebin.com/BRTZGRgA) I wrote. Maybe it's working now, The problem  is the active wait I think. I have that. and why my slot is not triggered ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use [waitForBytesWritten](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractsocket.html#waitForBytesWritten) and [waitForReadyRead](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractsocket.html#waitForReadyRead):

```cpp
// to receive datagrams, the socket needs to be bound to an address and port
m_imuRcvSocket.bind();

// send the initial message
QByteArray message("Hi it's Charly");

qint64 bytesSent= m_imuRcvSocket.writeDatagram(message,
                                               QHostAddress("200.0.0.3"),
                                               10000);

bool datagramWritten = m_imuRcvSocket.waitForBytesWritten();
// add code to check datagramWritten

datagram.resize(50); // random size for testing

bool datagramReady = m_imuRcvSocket.waitForReadyRead() && m_imuRcvSocket.hasPendingDatagrams();
// add code to check datagramReady

m_imuRcvSocket.readDatagram(datagram.data(),
                            datagram.size(),
                            &sender,
                            &senderPort);

cout << "================="
     << "\nMessage from <" << sender << "> on port " << senderPort
     << "\nString : " << datagram
     << "\nSize: " << pendingBytes << " Bytes (characters)\n"
     << "=================" <<
endl;
```

A better alternative would be to use signals and slots as described in the [documentation of QUdpSocket](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qudpsocket.html#details)

Answer (score 0):

if you plan to use the microprocessor as a client with UDP you need the MAC address of the destination machine otherwise it will not work. This one took me 4 hours to figure out.